# How do I return multiple rows from a JDBC method?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, return

I am currently learning JDBC and can successfully query and retrieve data from a MysQL database. But I would like to run this as a method and return the resultset rows from the method to the calling program.

So far I think I have made an appropriate method but am stuck returning the resultset as an `object`. Eclipse gives me the following error for the return type:

> Object cannot be resolved to a type

Here is the method:

```
public object getAllPosts(int catID) throws Exception{
    try{
        this.catID = catID;
        sql = "SELECT post_id, post_title, post_content, post_date FROM crm_posts WHERE cat_id = ? LIMIT ?";
        prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        prep.setInt(1, catID);
        prep.setInt(2, 3);
        // execute statement
        rs = prep.getResultSet();

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;
}
```

What is the return type I should use or is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT:

As stated in the comments it was a (annoying) typo. `Object` with a capital `O`.

Comment: Is it typo `object` in return type. It should be `Object`

Comment: Why don't you return a ResultSet? That way calling methods can use it without typecasting.

Comment: Thanks @Braj, feel free to make an answer, and thanks @Frazz Ill use `ResultSet`.

Comment: Just edit it in your post as solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to return a `ResultSet` or `Object` object, then you should define your return type. You could create your own `Post` object for each row in the `ResultSet`, put those objects in a list, and return the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it

```
public List<MyClassThatRepresentsTableInDatabase> getAllPosts(int catID) throws Exception{
    try{
        this.catID = catID;
        sql = "SELECT post_id, post_title, post_content, post_date FROM crm_posts WHERE cat_id = ? LIMIT ?";
        prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        prep.setInt(1, catID);
        prep.setInt(2, 3);
        // execute statement
        rs = prep.getResultSet();
        List<MyClassThatRepresentsTableInDatabase> ret=new ArrayList<>();
        while(rs.hasNext()){
           MyClassThatRepresentsTableInDatabase item=
                                 new MyClassThatRepresentsTableInDatabase();
           item.setId(rs.getLong("post_id");
           item.setName(rs.getString("post_title");
           item.setContentd("post_content");
           //etc..
           ret.add(item);
        }
        return ret;
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ArrayList();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excecute your query in ResultSet and loop it to get your results.

Use the following line of codes :

```
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()) 
{
     out.println(rs.getString("//Your Column name"));
}
```